# Why cant i check if i have included stdlib.h on tdm-gcc compiler?

Tags: c, gcc, include, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a header file in C and need `stdlib.h` for it to work. But, when I check if `_STDLIB_H` is defined, the pre-processor says it's not, even if I include the file. I have tried it on multiple compilers, where it works on most but not on `tdm-gcc`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to check that? Can't you just include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a safer way to check if `stdlib.h` is properly included, you should check for a macro that the C standard requires the file to define.

I may be missing something, but I don't see any requirement in the C standard for `stdlib.h` to define `_STDLIB_H`. I think this may just be a common way compilers decided to guard against multiple inclusion.

try something like

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef NULL
#error "stdlib.h not included"
#endif
```

because the C standard **requires** that `stdlib.h` defines `NULL`

But none of this should be technically necessary... I don't know of a preprocessor that won't throw a fatal error if it can't find a file you tried to `#include`

EDIT:

According to the C standard `stdio.h` also defines `NULL`, so perhaps it would be better to check for `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`

Comment: NULL is defined inside stdio.h as well. So in case the program includes stdio.h and not stdlib.h the error "stdlib.h not included" won't show.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [stdlib.h](https://github.com/jmeubank/tdm-gcc-src/blob/tdm-patches.public/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/tr1/stdlib.h) source code, it seems like the macro to look for in tdm-gcc might be `_TR1_STDLIB_H`.
So you can try something like:

```
#if defined _STDLIB_H || defined _TR1_STDLIB_H
```

Comment: On my computer, just _STDLIB_H worked for tdm-gcc v9.2.0. Even just _TR1_STDLIB_H worked. You can see the exact header that is being used by passing -M flag to the compiler. Then explore the header using a text editor.